# Not able to get dbms_output.put_line in cursor

Tags: plsql

while using cursor update from multiple tables **i am not  getting dbms_output.put_line** , *except that it is fine* ,only the problem is while using dbms_output and please find the table level information is also added that i am currenlty using

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

      DECLARE
          CURSOR c_update IS
            SELECT
            b.rowid   AS id,
            a.first_name,
            a.last_name
    FROM
        customer a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN customer2 b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id;

    TYPE t_data IS
        TABLE OF c_update%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;  --loading the data 
    of cursor into table
        x_data   t_data;   --instance variable decalrations
    BEGIN
        OPEN c_update;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_update BULK COLLECT INTO x_data;
        EXIT WHEN x_data.count = 0;
        FOR i IN x_data.first..x_data.last LOOP
            UPDATE customer2
            SET
                first_name = x_data(i).first_name
            WHERE
                ROWID = x_data(i).id;

        END LOOP;

        dbms_output.put_line(x_data.first_name); --getting error in this line
    END LOOP;

       CLOSE c_update;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
           dbms_output.put_line('The error is ' || sqlerrm);
    END;
```

**Table level information**

---

### --  File created - Tuesday-May-07-2019

---

### --  DDL for Table CUSTOMER2

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER2
   (    CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(5,0), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    ADDRESS_STATE VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    EMAIL_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(350 BYTE)
   ) 

Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (15,'John','Stock','ND','barl_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (1,'Teresa','Hudson','NY','bwal_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (2,'Fred','Montgomery','CA','fmont@gmail.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (3,'Lois','Lawson','WA','barl_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (4,'Alice','Perry','SC','barul_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (5,'Ralph','Montgomery','TX','ralph_mont25@gmail.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (6,'Dorothy','Armstrong','OR','abc123@abc.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (7,'Fred','Wallace','NY','walcef@testwebsite.co.uk');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (8,'Joseph','Bell','FL','baral_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (9,'Lois','Martinez','CALIF','loismar@awe.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (10,'Robert','Rice','IN','robrice123');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (12,'Joseph','Bell','OR','barul_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (5,'Ralph','Montgomery','TX','ralph_mont25@gmail.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (8,'Joseph','Bell','FL','barul_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (3,'Lois','Lawson','WA','barul_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (12,'Joseph','Bell','OR','baruwl_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (15,'John','Stock','ND','baruwl_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (1,'Teresa','Hudson','NY','baruwl_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (2,'Fred','Montgomery','CA','fmont@gmail.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (10,'Robert','Rice','IN','robrice123');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (6,'Dorothy','Armstrong','OR','abc123@abc.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (7,'Fred','Wallace','NY','wallacef@testwebsite.co.uk');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (4,'Alice','Perry','SC','baruwl_suman@outlook.com');
Insert into TBAADM.CUSTOMER2 (CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_STATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS) values (9,'Lois','Martinez','CALIF','loismar@awe.com');
```

**and for customer table**

```
create table customer as select * from customer2;
update customer set EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'firsttableemail@gmail.com';
```

Comment: try dbms_output.put_line(i.first_name);  inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection variable of a composite type can't be used to access a column directly like a record variable. It should refer to a particular index and then the column.

```
dbms_output.put_line(x_data(i).first_name);
```

It is not clear if you want to display the last entry, as you have used it outside the `FOR` loop. If you want to display each entry, move it within the `LOOP`. The above will not work if it is outside the loop as the reference to `i` would be invalid.

**EDIT**

I changed your code slightly with your provided data and it seems to work for me. Check the DBiddle demo below.

```
DECLARE
     CURSOR c_update IS
     SELECT
            b.rowid   AS id,
            a.first_name,
            a.last_name
             FROM
        customer a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN customer2 b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id;

     TYPE t_data IS
        TABLE OF c_update%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
     x_data t_data; 
    BEGIN
        OPEN c_update;
     FETCH c_update BULK COLLECT INTO x_data;
            FOR i IN x_data.first..x_data.last LOOP
          UPDATE customer2
          SET
               first_name = x_data(i).first_name
          WHERE ROWID = x_data(i).id;
          dbms_output.put_line(x_data(i).first_name);
     END LOOP;

     CLOSE c_update;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
           dbms_output.put_line('The error is ' || sqlerrm);
END;
/
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ad553a76533d375495948b91fd6e2677)

Comment: **PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'**  while used dbms_output.put_line(x_data(1).first_name);  i tried inside for loop and outside for loop it is giving me same error

Comment: @Suman : I think you're including something else as well in your `dbms_output`

Comment: I can run this line of codesset serveroutput on;
declare 
x_num  number :=13;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(x_num);
end;      **what is the actual problem i get strucked** @Kaushik Nayak

Comment: can you proceed same as you commented from multiple table by join operation and *test dbms_output*

Comment: @Suman : Edit your question and add table definitions and some sample data required for us to simulate your problem. A [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2) would be even better

Comment: Kaushik Nayak  please find the edit with table level information is also attached with it

Answer (score 1):

This code *simulates* what you're doing (without the `UPDATE` statement, it is irrelevant here); as I don't have your tables, I used Scott's schema. Also, I don't know what is the outer loop used for in your case. `BULK COLLECT` doesn't need it (so I removed it).

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor c_update is
  3      select deptno, dname, loc
  4      from dept
  5      where deptno >= 20;
  6
  7    type   t_data is table of dept%rowtype index by binary_integer;
  8    x_data t_data;
  9  begin
 10    open  c_update;
 11    fetch c_update bulk collect into x_data;
 12    close c_update;
 13
 14    for i in x_data.first .. x_data.last loop
 15      dbms_output.put_line(x_data(i).dname);
 16    end loop;
 17  end;
 18  /
RESEARCH
SALES
OPERATIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: Join in a cursor declaration example]**

Why wouldn't it work if there's a join involved?

```
SQL> create table t_update
  2    (deptno number, dname varchar2(10), loc varchar2(10), ename varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    cursor c_update is
  3      select d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc, e.ename
  4      from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  5      where d.deptno >= 20
  6      order by d.deptno;
  7
  8    type   t_data is table of t_update%rowtype index by binary_integer;
  9    x_data t_data;
 10  begin
 11    open  c_update;
 12    fetch c_update bulk collect into x_data;
 13      close c_update;
 14
 15    for i in x_data.first .. x_data.last loop
 16      dbms_output.put_line(x_data(i).dname ||' - '|| x_data(i).ename);
 17    end loop;
 18  end;
 19  /
RESEARCH - SMITH
RESEARCH - ADAMS
RESEARCH - JONES
RESEARCH - SCOTT
RESEARCH - FORD
SALES - JAMES
SALES - TURNER
SALES - MARTIN
SALES - WARD
SALES - ALLEN
SALES - BLAKE
OPERATIONS -

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: can you proceed the same thing using join operation in cursor declaration and taking dbms_output

Comment: Sure, why not? It works just the same. Join isn't responsible for your problems. I edited my answer; have a look, please.